# How execute R script in Task Scheduler without the terminal opening

Tags: r, windows, batch-file, rscript

I automated the triggering of an R script in the task scheduler. When the task must be carried out, a terminal opens then executes the script. What I want is to run the script without the terminal opening, the execution must be done in the background.

I created a .bat file that launches the R script

**.bat**

```
"C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.3/bin/Rscript.exe" "C:/Workspace/script/script.R"
```

I tried to put commands but either the terminal still opens or the script does nothing:

```
start /B /MIN "../Rscript.exe" "../script.R"
"../R.exe" CMD BATCH "../script.R"
```

Comment: try, in your .bat file: `start /B /MIN "" "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.3/bin/Rscript.exe" "C:/Workspace/script/script.R"`